# React Native with Redux: mapStateToProps()-function is not updating

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working at a React Native and Redux project with several reducers, that are combined through combineReducers().

I have one component, that doesn't dispatches any actions but only shows information from the redux state. It is connected to this state with the connect function:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // some code
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Text>
        { this.props.value }
      </Text>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state.updaterReducer.value,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
) (MyComponent);
```

There's another part/component in the project, that changes the redux state and value:

```
import { makeUpdate } from './updater.actions.js';
import configureStore from '@redux/configureStore.js';
const store = configureStore();

// This function is can be called by some buttons in the app:
export default function update() {
  console.log('Update function called');
  store.dispatch(makeUpdate());
}
```

And here's my problem: when update is called, the updater-action and the updater-reducer are both called, so that the redux state changes, but 'MyComponent' never updates.

Comment: Sorry, I misread and deleted the answer. Indeed that should work. Are you sure the state is updated by the other component ? You can verify with the redux dev tools or post it there to have an overview of the problem

Comment: Yes, I can verify, that the state is updated, because I put a console.log() in the regarding reducer...   I now tried another thing: I added a mapDispatchToProps() and changed the state from 'MyComponent'. Now mapStateToProps(9 updated the props correctly. But that's not my aim, because 'MyComponent' isn't supposed to change the state at the end...

Comment: Very strange, I don't know how to help... perhaps you can share a codesandbox ?

Comment: I think this is not possible since I have no React project but a React Native project. But I'll try to organize a small verifiable example case and upload the code...

Comment: No I have added some more code. I hope, that helps...

Comment: I Paul, nothing seems wrong in this component too, if you still have the problem can you zip and upload the project on a cloud ? I'll try to figure out what happens

Comment: @Palisanka Thank you very much for this offer, but I found the (very dump) failure on my own in the end (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem on my own: The solution was very easy in the end, but couldn't be found on the basis of the code in the original question: Every time I needed the redux-store, I used a configureStore-function from a web-tutorial to create it on basis of the reducers. So I created multiple times the 'same' store. Unfortunately these stores were not connected to each other...

Sometimes that worked in the project, because a mapStateToProps-function and a mapDispatchToProps-function both were in the the same component and used **one** store, but sometimes (like in the example in the question) those functions used different stores and couldn't influence each other.